# How to create hoverable dropdown menu that shows selected variable

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for some (probably easy) advice which I cant seem to find googling. I have a hoverable dropdown menu such as:

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.btn {
  background-color: #D6182D;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .btn {
  background-color: rgb(134, 30, 42);
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Chose a month to display</a>

    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/jan">
        <font color="black">January 2018</font>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="/feb">
        <font color="black">February 2018</font>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="/mar">
        <font color="black">March 2018</font>
      </a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="/tot">
        <font color="black">Total</font>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```

Basically taken from w3schools..

Now instead of "Chose a month to display" I would like to display the chosen option once someone clicks on it. Do you guys have any idea on how to change the code to do so?

Looking forward to your answers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I made some changes in your HTML to make it more semantic and for dropdown text, you can try plain javascript. I hope, This will help you.**

**For old value, you can store your value somewhere, like in localstorage**

For Example, I am saving old selected value in local storage.

```
const months = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
if(localStorage.getItem("oldval")){
 document.getElementById("dropdownMenuLink").innerHTML = 
 localStorage.getItem("oldval"); 
}
Array.from(months).map(month=>{
 month.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
 let selectedValue = e.target.textContent;
 document.getElementById("dropdownMenuLink").innerHTML = 
 selectedValue;
 localStorage.setItem("oldval",selectedValue);
});
});
```

```js
const months = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");

Array.from(months).map(month=>{
  month.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    let selectedValue = e.target.textContent;
    document.getElementById("dropdownMenuLink").innerHTML = selectedValue;
  });
});
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.btn {
  background-color: #D6182D;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  min-width: 200px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 10px;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}


/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */

.dropdown:hover .btn {
  background-color: rgb(134, 30, 42);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <center>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Chose a month to display</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-content">
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="/jan">
        January 2018
        </a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="/feb">
        February 2018
        </a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="/mar">
        March 2018
        </a></li>
      <li><a class="nav-link" href="/tot">
        Total
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Exactly what I needed! The snippet runs super nice here but unfortunately not when I run the whole thing locally. Any idea why this could be? Maybe some problems with bootstrap ?

Comment: Where do you suggest me to insert the <script></script> part? Inside the header?

Comment: @Riposte After the DOM Loading, I mean at the end of the body, you can insert your script.

Comment: thanks for your help! its working now but it stopped redirecting me :-( trying to figure out where it comes from

Comment: @Riposte you can remove e.preventDefault(); from script if redirection is your requirement.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Works now with the redirection but if I chose e.g "January 2018" it says "January 2018" inside the menu only as long as its loading. Once its redirected it shows me: "Chose a month to display" again. Is there any way that it redirects me and shows the current choice at the same time?

Comment: @Riposte okay, for that, you can store your old selected value in localstorage. I have added js code in snippet. you can try that one in place of the old one. If you like it, please upvote the above answer

Comment: I have done that Kumar. They say it doesn't show but is recorded as I have less than 15 contributions. Thanks! :-) Do you know why it shows me "Total" instead of "Chose..." now when I reload the page? Other than that It works perfectly fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

as i can see you are using `<div>` and `<a>` to achieve a drop-down which is not wrong at all but is not correct way of html to do it.

Read about `<select>` and `<option>` tag which will help you to get a drop-down effect as well as you can set `value` inside `<option>` tag dynamically as you click it. by using `getElementById('id-of-element')`

[read about getElementById here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)

Also if you want some redirection when user clicks it you can use `<a>` tag inside `<option>` tag.

[select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

hope this will help you, post any doubts if you have will be happy to help you :-)